# Want a reverse button for my image Array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, reverse

Hello I have just created the following JavaScript code for a next button which when clicked will show the next image in my array. However I now want to reverse this by creating a new function for a "Previous" button which goes back down the array rather than forward. This will be much more images than just the 3 example ones you see in this Array:

```
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = "Media//Gallery//img_1.jpg";

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "Media//Gallery//img_2.jpg";

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = "Media//Gallery//img_3.jpg";
```

This is my Next buttons function. I just need to reverse it for the Previous button but not sure how.

```
function nextImage(event) {
    var img = document.getElementById("largeImage");

    for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src)
        {
            if(i === imgArray.length){
                img.src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the div for the previous button:

```
<div class="imgNav" onclick="previousImage(this);" style="width:190px">
```

This is the image which I want to change when you press the button:

```
<img id="largeImage" src="Media//Gallery//Image_1.jpg" alt="Large Image" />
```

Thank you so vety much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

JavaScript

```
    currentIndex = 0;

    function changeImage(direction)
    {
        var index = currentIndex + direction;

       if (index < 0)
       {
           index = 0; // or use imgArray.length to rotate round
       }

       if (index > imgArray.length)
       {
           index = imgArray.length; // or use 0 to rotate round
       }

       document.getElementById('largeImage').src = imgArray[index].src;
       currentIndex = index;
    }
```

Html Code

```
<div class="imgNav" onclick="changeImage(-1)" style="width:190px">

<div class="OtherimgNav" onclick="changeImage(1)" style="width:190px">
```

Comment: Hmm that definitely looks simpler but I cannot seem to get it to work. Will keep trying

Comment: sorry I left a line in which used jQuery use the updated code :)

Comment: Still can't this to work. The original code which I linked works but only for swapping to the next array value. Is there anyone I can use that code instead but just reverse it to do the opposite?

Comment: When I press any of the buttons that use the function, it just shows an empty image frame rather than the next one in the array :/

Comment: I had a bug in the code it wasn't getting the .src of the loaded image it should now work.  When you post questions to do with java script btw or html make a jsFiddle it is quicker to provide a fix.  I coded that off the top of my head hence the glitches :)

Comment: oh ok. Thank you very much. It does work however because of the way my images are I need the order to reset because when I go into the first image and go through the array it works fine but when I exit and click on the 4th image on the page for example, the order is all wrong. The image below shows what the page looks like to help explain what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/NgQk5P2.jpg